# Integration of one form

Tags: real-analysis, integration, differential-forms, curves

$\omega=p(x,y)dx+q(x,y)dy\quad$ a continuously differentiable one form and $d\omega =0$

In addition, for $\alpha(t)=(r\cos t,r\sin t)$, $\int_\alpha \omega =0 $ for some $\; r \in \mathbb R$

I need to prove that

$$\int_\gamma{\omega}=0 $$ for any closed $\gamma$.

Can someone give me a hint because I don't know where to start. I know that $\; \int_\gamma{\omega}=0$ would be true if I could find a function $\; f$ so that $\;V=\text{grad}(f)=(p,q)$ but I don't think that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a standard arguemnt using Stokes' Theorem. Let $\gamma (t)$ be a parametrization of $\gamma$. Then consider

$$F : \mathbb S^1 \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2, $$

where $F(t, s) = s \alpha (t) + (1-s) \gamma (t)$. Then $F(\cdot, 0) = \gamma$ and $F(\cdot, 1) = \alpha$. Using Stokes' Theorem, as $d\omega = 0$,

$$0=\int_{\mathbb S^1 \times [0,1]} F^* d\omega = \int_{\partial{(\mathbb S^1 \times [0,1])}}F^*\omega = \int_{\mathbb S^1 \times \{1\}} F^*\omega - \int_{\mathbb S^1 \times \{0\}} F^*\omega = \int_\alpha \omega - \int_\gamma \omega.$$

Thus $\int_\gamma \omega =0$ for any closed $\gamma$.

Comment: You made a typo $8 \;$instead of $\; *$ ?

Comment: @XPenguen : Yes, edited.

Comment: Could you explain to me why $\; \int_{\partial{(\mathbb S^1 \times [0,1])}}F^*\omega = \int_{\mathbb S^1 \times \{1\}} F^*\omega - \int_{\mathbb S^1 \times \{0\}} F^*\omega \;$ ?

Comment: that's because $\partial (\mathbb S^1 \times [0,1]) = \mathbb S^1 \times \{0\} \cup \mathbb S^1 \times \{1\}$ (here $\partial$ denotes the boundary). There's a -ve sign for $\int_{\mathbb S^1 \times \{0\}} \omega$ is because we need to take into account the orientation of the boundary. @XPenguen